# How to disable write-cache for USB in Ubuntu for safe yanking without "Eject" or "Safely Remove"?

Tags: 10.04, usb

In Windows, I can edit the usb properties like in the following picture

[image]

So I want to ask how can we edit the removal policy like that in Ubuntu ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5051/how-to-switch-off-caching-for-usb-device-when-writing-to-it or http://superuser.com/questions/526248/turn-off-write-cache-on-all-usb-external-drives-debian-ubuntu-linux Besided that: 10.04 is off topic I believe(?)

Comment: It seems the second link is helpful, so I have to issue this command
 hdparm -W0K1 /dev/sdb
for my usb in sdb ? 

And sorry for the extra 10.04 tag.

Comment: @Rinzwind 10.04 is not off topic exactly. The 'desktop' product is still alive, until some point this month, and the server product is still supported until April 2015. There hasn't been an EOL announcement for 10.04 'desktop' yet though.