# USB memory stick is "broken" after files are copied

Tags: 13.10, usb, windows-8

I have installed on my computer both `Ubuntu 13.10` and `Windows 8` and lately noticed that while a large file is copied with 5-6 MB per second on `Windows 8` its transferred with up to 80 MB per second on the `Ubuntu 13.10`.

What I am doing is downloading movies, copping them on a `USB` stick and watch them on my TV. So, because the speed on `Ubuntu` is better, a prefer to do the downloading and copying part using it.

The issue is so far, I have not successfully copy anything. I am using three different `USB` sticks formatted as `NTFS` and all copy operations are falling.

Firstly, the files are transferred but when I eject/inject the `USB` again, I get the following error:

> Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/gotqn/Joro: Command-line `mount -t
>   "ntfs" -o
>   "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177"
>   "/dev/sdb1" "/media/gotqn/Joro"' exited with non-zero exit status 13:
>   $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0). Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1':
>   Input/output error NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware
>   fault, or it's a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run
>   chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the
>   /f parameter is very important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID
>   then first activate it and mount a different device under the
>   /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g. /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please
>   see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details.

I have firstly thought that there might be something with the `USB` sticks themselves, so  I have formatted them using `gparted` to `NTFS` again but nothing changes.

When I formatted the sticks  on `Windows 8` and copied the files, everything is OK.

How to fix this?

Comment: @arhimed I think you can write that as an answer. 80Mb/sec is impossible on USB2.0 and also very-very unlikely on USB3 for a pendrive. The only question is if gotqn is ejecting his drive correctly (then this is a bug) or he just pulls it out (then this is a user error).

Comment: @falconer this seems to be a user error, because I have ejected the `USB` since the system tells me the files are copied (but they are not).

Comment: I think this problem is related to the NTFS fileystem. Because for me my fat formatted drives are automounted with the `flush` option, but your NTFS is not. Just tried an NTFS external HDD and it is indeed not automounted with `flush`. So I think you just have to format your drives to FAT32. Anyway FAT32 is the normal option for pendrives, not even Microsoft recommends NTFS for pendrives/memory-cards. (Maybe you are limited by the FAT32 filesystem capabilities (e.g. max file size) and that is why you need NTFS? ) Or maybe you can tweak `udisks` to automount your drives with `flush`.

Answer (score 2):

As @falconer pointed out, 80MB/sec is impossible on USB2.0 and also very-very unlikely on USB3 for a pendrive.

The reason of such fast speed is probably writing cache. While the Copy Dialog shows you 80MB/s, the actually write speed is 5-6MB/s and OS caching everything rest and write it later. So even Copy Dialog report about files are copied, they're actually not.

OS still writing on the disk and if you press Unmount option on drive it will tell you that there are operations with the drive and you need to wait. After a several minutes(or more if files are big ones) it actually finish write data on drive and make pendrive inactive. Than you can eject drive and open files on other PC or TV.

There are two posts questions that may help you with disabling writing cache:
[How to switch off caching for usb device when writing to it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5051/how-to-switch-off-caching-for-usb-device-when-writing-to-it)
and 
https://superuser.com/questions/526248/turn-off-write-cache-on-all-usb-external-drives-debian-ubuntu-linux

I used the second one for my problem and it helped me. I have only one hard disk drive in my laptop(/dev/sda), so any other drive is removable. Also I have 2 usb ports so I can connect 2 external drives maximum(/dev/sdb and /dev/sdc) so i've added to `/etc/hdparm.conf`

```
/dev/sdb {
        write_cache = off
}
/dev/sdc {
        write_cache = off
}
```

Comment: I try to disable it, but the speed remains the same. When I put into the `USB` the `gparted` show it as `/dev/sdb`, but when I run `sudo fdisk -l` it is shown as `/dev/sdb1`. I have entered the both  cases in the `/etc/hdparam.conf` but nothing change. Should I restart the `Ubuntu` or do something else?