# Alert the user when they unsafely unplug an USB thumb drive

Tags: usb, udev, unmount, notify-send

Users repeatedly complain about lost data on USB thumb drives after they unplugged them without unmounting. We run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on our machines. Auto-mounting is enabled.

As I am tired of remembering them to do a safe removal before unplugging, I want to make Ubuntu display an alert whenever a mounted USB drive is unplugged.

I thought of adding an `udev` rule that runs `notify-send` on removal in case the drive is still mounted. **How can I determine if the USB drive was mounted upon removal?**

Comment: So you've said that auto-mounting is enabled, but then you ask "how can I determine if the usb that fired udev rule was mounted?" . Now, I think you mean you need to determine the state of USB upon removal - mounted or unmounted. I'd personally approach this with a startup script that merely monitors the mounting/unmounting time of the usb with `df -a | grep 'sd[b-z]' ` command. A udev rule can send date of removal to a log of some sort. If the time of removal given by the script matches that of udev rule (at least by minutes, with the seconds there may be delay), then usb wasnt mounted.

Comment: Here's also a script that i wrote for the logging purposes. http://paste.ubuntu.com/11748191/  If you like this idea, I could post this as an answer, but I personally consider these two comments a suggestion, rather than a working solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like Fabby's approach, but it is good to teach people about this bad habit (They are not working all the time on controlled machines). This is similar to an OSX feature, as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/how-do-i-disable-this-message-the-disk-was-not-ejected-properly).

There is a small difference that you may use it to know if it was a safe remove:

- udev variable `ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos` is set for `sdx` disk node (*NOT partition node `sdxY`*) in unsafe remove.
- Where it is not set in safe remove

Noticed by monitoring udev events:

```
udevadm monitor -u --environment
```

- **Safe remove**

  ```
  UDEV  [8292.380554] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host16/target16:0:0/16:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
  ACTION=change
  DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-ADATA_USB_Flash_Drive_8d90ec535e6663-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
  DEVNAME=/dev/sdb
  DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host16/target16:0:0/16:0:0:0/block/sdb
  DEVTYPE=disk
  DISK_MEDIA_CHANGE=1
  ID_BUS=usb
  ID_INSTANCE=0:0
  ID_MODEL=USB_Flash_Drive
  ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Flash\x20Drive\x20
  ID_MODEL_ID=c96a
  ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
  ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
  ID_REVISION=0.00
  ID_SERIAL=ADATA_USB_Flash_Drive_8d90ec535e6663-0:0
  ID_SERIAL_SHORT=8d90ec535e6663
  ID_TYPE=disk
  ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
  ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
  ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
  ID_VENDOR=ADATA
  ID_VENDOR_ENC=ADATA\x20\x20\x20
  ID_VENDOR_ID=125f
  MAJOR=8
  MINOR=16
  SEQNUM=2989
  SUBSYSTEM=block                                                              
  TAGS=:systemd:                                                               
  USEC_INITIALIZED=554873
  ```
- **Unsafe remove**

  ```
  UDEV  [8391.320280] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
  ACTION=remove
  DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-ADATA_USB_Flash_Drive_8d90ec535e6663-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
  DEVNAME=/dev/sdb
  DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/block/sdb
  DEVTYPE=disk
  ID_BUS=usb
  ID_INSTANCE=0:0
  ID_MODEL=USB_Flash_Drive
  ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Flash\x20Drive\x20
  ID_MODEL_ID=c96a
  ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
  ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
  ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_3_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
  ID_REVISION=0.00
  ID_SERIAL=ADATA_USB_Flash_Drive_8d90ec535e6663-0:0
  ID_SERIAL_SHORT=8d90ec535e6663
  ID_TYPE=disk
  ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
  ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
  ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
  ID_VENDOR=ADATA
  ID_VENDOR_ENC=ADATA\x20\x20\x20
  ID_VENDOR_ID=125f
  MAJOR=8
  MINOR=16
  SEQNUM=3022
  SUBSYSTEM=block
  TAGS=:systemd:
  USEC_INITIALIZED=436355
  ```

---

1. Create a udev rule (change `useranme`)

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/90-unsafe-remove-notify.rules

   ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="sd?", ENV{ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE}!="", RUN+="/usr/bin/sudo -u username DISPLAY=:0 notify-send 'Unsafe Remove' '<b><i>Your long message</b></i>' -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/emotes/face-worried.png -t 10000"
   ```
2. Reload rules

   ```
   sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
   ```

---

Another way, you may use a script (python) that connect to `udisks` DBUS. It has all needed info you need about partition  mount/unmount, disks plug/unplug...

**Reference/Source:** [Gentoo Wiki: Udisks - USB_Thumb_Drive_Example](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Udisks#USB_Thumb_Drive_Example)

Comment: While I do like Fabby's approach, this is what I was looking for!
I now plan on writing a python script that listens for `udisks` events on DBUS and then handles the display of message dialogs, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, that's a thing Micro$oft actually got quite right: USB removal... And you'll keep on having this problem until you:

1. Disable auto-mounting

   If users have to mount manually, it'll be easier to train them to dismount as well.
2. Create a udev rule that [turns off all caching on USB disks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5051/how-to-switch-off-caching-for-usb-device-when-writing-to-it)...

Comment: +1 - disabling the cache helps reduce the problem. As long as they don't unplug the device during a write (which usually causes an LED on the device to light up / flash) they will be alright.

Comment: Okay, that'd work well on the computer side. But doesn't disabling cache or setting sync flag on mount burn out the flash chip rather quickly? Those USB drives are all VFAT and I heard Linux is quite aggressive at updating FAT tables - wearing out the sectors containing the table.

Comment: I only buy [SLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Single-level_cell) sticks and haven't had any die on me yet regardless of the file system... (and I only have 2)

Comment: @RenWal: As you've never accepted an answer on this site: don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid!](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: FWIW, Windows disables write cache on FAT-formatted USB drives by default, for the same reasons, so I guess any extra wear on the drive was seen as a lesser evil.