# Hibernating from cron

Tags: 16.04, cron, hibernate, systemd, automation

I am trying to hibernate from cron using the command `systemctl hibernate`. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to start hibernate.target: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status hibernate.target' for details.
```

If I execute the above command manually from terminal, it works as expected.

**How do I hibernate from cron?**

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: How about `pm-hibernate`?

Comment: That requires `sudo` to run.

Comment: Yep, It need root access, So you need `sudo` when test using your user. but system`cron` already running as root (only if you are trying to use user's cron)

Comment: If I run it without prefixing `sudo`, I get the error `This utility may only be run by the root user.`.  With `sudo`, I get the error - `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.

Comment: If I schedule it with `sudo crontab -e`, both of the commands are working. But, is there any way to do it from normal crontab itself ? I guess [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pm-utils#User_permission_method) will do for the `pm-hibernate` command. But isn't `systemctl` better than `pm-utils` ([source](http://superuser.com/questions/323484/what-do-the-power-management-tools-in-linux-do-acpi-pm-utils-etc)) ?

Comment: [Related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90817/command-not-running-in-cron-systemctl-suspend).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because it needs root privileges.
The solution is to add the hibernate command using `sudo crontab -e -u root` instead of `crontab -e`.

> **polkit** is necessary for power management as an unprivileged user. If
>   you are in a local systemd-logind user session and no other session is
>   active, the following commands will work without root privileges. If
>   not (for example, because another user is logged into a tty), systemd
>   will automatically ask you for the root password.

Power management commands:

```
systemctl reboot|poweroff|suspend|hibernate|hybrid-sleep
```

**Reference**: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Power_management

Comment: The first 2 steps can be replaced by 1 - `sudo crontab -e`. And `systemctl` works too this way.

Comment: Yep I just wanted to confirm root level.  `systemctl` I agree seems to be the future tool. I will look if there another using it at user level

Comment: You didn't answer why my current method isn't working. `systemctl hibernate` is working without root when run manually. Then, why is it not running from cron ?

Comment: Really!!! It does not work for me only with root power (sudo). But think I have seen a question here before about similar thing related to auto  shutdown using DBus., the command should be launch from terminal (tty) with the user already passed the login.

Comment: Oh wow! What Ubuntu version are you using ?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as yours but installed on VBox (I didn't want to reboot may machine)  it just keep waiting till I cancel ctrl+c, In the real machine too 16.04 (upgraded from 15.10)  I got a GUI dialog to enter my passwd if I cancel it I got same messages you mention in the question

Comment: Sadly, `notify-send` isn't working on root cron. Do you know any solution to that ?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi, yes here is https://askubuntu.com/questions/638867/alert-the-user-when-they-unsafely-unplug-an-usb-thumb-drive/

Comment: I am sorry, but how does that link help ?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi sorry for such long question, here directly the wanted command  `/usr/bin/sudo -u username DISPLAY=:0 notify-send 'Unsafe Remove' '<b><i>Your long message</b></i>' -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/emotes/face-worried.png -t 10000`  ,  you may find some differences on other answer. if you want to see search here for `udev  notify-send` , `acpi  notify-send`  & `cron notify-send`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41049/discussion-between-anmol-singh-jaggi-and-sneetsher).

Comment: Like user.dz [said](http://askubuntu.com/a/785596/649983 "said"), add hibernate to root's crontab, but I would use a slightly different command to launch crontab: sudo crontab -e -u root From `man crontab` :
"Note that su(8) can confuse crontab and that if you are running inside of su(8) you should always use the -u option for safety's sake." I don't know if crontab has the same problem with sudo that it has with su, but, may as well play it safe. (I would have added this as a comment to user.dz answer, but, I don't have the rep.)

Answer (score 3):

[The other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/785596/173003) is great! But it requires root cron.

If you want to hibernate from non-sudo cron, there are 2 options:

### 1. Using [polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit)

Make a file containing the following:

```
[Enable hibernate to be run via cron]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=yes
```

named `com.0.enable-hibernation-from-cron.pkla` in the directory `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`.

Explanation is given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289123/explanation-of-file-org-freedesktop-login1-policy).

### 2. Using [visudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)

Quoting from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/allow_users_to_shutdown#Users_without_sudo_privileges):

> If users should only be allowed to use shutdown commands, but not have
>   other sudo privileges, then, as root, add the following to the end of
>   *`/etc/sudoers`* using the `visudo` command.
>
> ```
> user hostname =NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl poweroff,/usr/bin/systemctl halt,/usr/bin/systemctl reboot
> ```
>
> Substitute `user` for your username and `hostname` for the machine's hostname.
>   Now your user can shutdown with `sudo systemctl poweroff`, and reboot
>   with `sudo systemctl reboot`. Users wishing to power down a system can
>   also use `sudo systemctl halt`.
>   Use the NOPASSWD: tag only if you do not want to be prompted for your password.

In my case, the exact line is:

```
anmol ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl hibernate
```

(Note that the location of `systemctl` might be different on your system.)

After this, you can write `sudo systemctl hibernate` fron cron to hibernate.

Note: Directly modifying *`/etc/sudoers`* is [bad](https://superuser.com/q/869144/241498); instead make a custom sudoers file under *`/etc/sudoers.d/`* using the command - `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/custom`.

Comment: Great, [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) is  another reference for polkit option from Ubuntu help pages.  Possible to use `Identity=unix-user:username` to give permission to one user only same as the sudoer solution.

Comment: I found this worked for me when the command is `sudo /bin/systemctl hibernate`.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian SID this worked for me:

1. In `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/cron-suspend.rules` file add:

   ```
   polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
        if (subject.user == "my-user" && (action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend" || action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-session")) {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
        }
   });
   ```
2. Restart the service:

   ```
   systemctl restart polkit
   ```

OBS: change `suspend` to `hibernate` if needed.