# Notification not showing up by script run by udev rules

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts, udev

I made a script that displays a notificaiton whenever I unplug the charger. I made the script to run by udev by making a rule in rules.d. The problem is the script run fine but the notification didn't show up. So far I know that the script requires the address of the display server, here is what my rule and script looks like.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority
/usr/bin/notify-send --urgency=critical -i face-cool "Charger removed"
zenity --info --text 'Happy New Year'
```

Here is the rule that I created

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS}=="Discharging", RUN+="/home/user/alertchargerremoved.sh"
```

Is there any other way to notify myself when the charger is removed, like instead of notification which doesn't require the X server? Do you have any other ideas, how can accomplish this thing?

Comment: Theoretically less clean, but very easy to set up: use a small background script running `acpi -a` once per five seconds or so, in case of change in output > show notification.

Comment: I found a workaround by adding root user as `xhost +si:localuser:root` and the script worked, but is it safe to do so? I will be adding this command in startup.

Answer (score 0):

I have this worked for me before:

```
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="sd?", ENV{ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE}!="", RUN+="/usr/bin/sudo -u username DISPLAY=:0 notify-send 'Unsafe Remove' '<b><i>Your long message</b></i>' -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/emotes/face-worried.png -t 10000"
```

From: [Alert the user when they unsafely unplug an USB thumb drive](https://askubuntu.com/a/640703/26246)

So use `sudo` to run `notify-send` as same user (Not as `root`)

```
/usr/bin/sudo -u username notify-send ...
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't work in terminal, I doubt that it will work in the rules, Can you please check if the Command that you wrote in RUN works in your terminal?

Comment: @HemantYadav , yes it is still working https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZaRf.png

Comment: @HemantYadav, Did you find any solution?