# How can I avoid data loss after removing NTFS usb without unmounting

Tags: partitioning, usb, permissions, mount, ntfs

I want to configure `fstab` in that way that my USB will be mounted automatically. My Hardware has two USB plug. I want to configure one of them for FAT32 and another for NTFS.

I added this two lines to the `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/da1s1  /mnt/usb1 ntfs mountprog=/usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g,rw,noauto,late 0   0        
/dev/da2s1  /mnt/usb2 msdosfs rw,noauto,-m=777,-M=777                     0   0
```

Now they will be automatically mounted if I insert proper USB but after removing them there is data loss by NTFS Format USB (FAT32 is ok).

Can anybody help me how can I solve this problem?
thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch off caching for usb device when writing to it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5051/how-to-switch-off-caching-for-usb-device-when-writing-to-it). Also: [_How to Disable Disk Write Caching in Ubuntu To Prevent Data Loss_](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/disable-disk-caching-prevent-data-loss/)